# Modifying style and multibinding conditionally

Tags: c#, validation, xaml, styles, multibinding

I have a simple XAML that looks as below:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Converters:ButtonVisibilityConverter x:Key="m_ButtonConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="71,18,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="229" SelectionChanged="comboBox1_SelectionChanged">              
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="71,76,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="229" Style="{StaticResource requiredFieldValidationStyle}"/>
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="71,125,0,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="229" Style="{StaticResource requiredFieldValidationStyle}"/>        
    <Button Content="Submit" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="225,175,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75">
        <Button.IsEnabled>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource m_ButtonConverter}">
                <Binding ElementName="textBox1" Path="Text" />
                <Binding ElementName="textBox2" Path="Text" />
                <Binding ElementName="comboBox1" Path="Text" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Button.IsEnabled>
    </Button>
    <Label Content="Box 1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,74,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Label Content="Box 2" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,123,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
```

textbox1 and textbox2 are both mandatory fields now, and that the button does not enable unless both boxes have text.

I want to do the following: When an even number is selected in the combobox, I want to make textbox2 entry as optional. That means, I remove it from the multibinding (of the button's IsEnabled) and also remove the style. However, when an odd number is chosen, I want them back.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it by conditionally checking in the xaml.cs file on the selectionchanged event of the combobox.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selVal = (int)comboBox1.SelectedValue;

        if ((selVal % 2) == 0)
        {
            // remove the style
            textBox2.Style = null;

            // remove from the button's IsEnabled multibinding                 
            _vfs.NumberValidationFlag = false;
            BindingOperations.ClearBinding(button1, Button.IsEnabledProperty);
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(button1, Button.IsEnabledProperty, GetBindingForButton());                
        }
        else
        {
            // add back the style
            Style myStyle = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["requiredFieldValidationStyle"];
            textBox2.Style = myStyle;

            // add back to the button's IsEnabled multibinding                
            _vfs.NumberValidationFlag = true;
            BindingOperations.ClearBinding(button1, Button.IsEnabledProperty);
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(button1, Button.IsEnabledProperty, GetBindingForButton());
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this works, how much harder have you made it to create automated unit tests.  Also, this is business logic (optional data in certain situations) that you have embedded into your UI.  Maybe this is a small one off application and doesn't need the complexity of MVVM, but I want others who might find this solution to consider the downsides of this solution.

Comment: I agree. Do you suggest a better solution without converting it to MVVM?

Answer (score 0):

I think changing the `MultiBinding` based on optional entries will be problematic. My suggestion is to use a ViewModel and create a Dependency Property for the IsButtonEnabled and put the logic for optional entryies and validation in the ViewModel. Then you can just binding to the `IsButtonEnabled` DP.

Comment: Thanks. But I am intending to do it this way or anyway without creating a ViewModel. Can you please help?